# Recursive definition for multiplication of polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recursion

I want to find a base and step case for my definition of the multiplication of polynomials that only uses lists.

Whenever I try to make a definition I either use some input (which shouldn't be done) or I access some elements that are not the first element.

To give a  clearer image, for example, the polynomial $3x^2 + 9x + 1$ is represented as $[1, 9, 3]$

So at the end, if I used my definition $[1, 9, 3]$ and $[1, 2]$ should give $[1, 11, 21, 6]$ which is equivalent to $6x^3+ 21x^2 + 11x + 1$ and the same for any two lists (polynomials)

---

Polynomials addition example

Base Cases f:
$$f([],[]) = []$$
$$f(s:l,[]) = s :f(l,[])$$

$$f([],s:l) = s:f([],l)$$

Step case f:

$$f(s_a:l_a, s_b:l_b) = (s_a+s_b):f(l_a,l_b)$$

$[]$ is the empty list

---

any help is appreciated

Comment: To check if I understood it correctly, isnt it $f(s:l,[])=s:f(l,[])$?

Comment: That is correct. I forgot to include it, I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1):

Given two lists (coefficient sequencies) $[a_0,...,a_n]$ and $[b_0,...,b_m]$, you are looking for the list $[c_0,...,c_{n+m}]$, which describes the product of the polynomials given by the initial lists. I think what you are looking for can be derived like this:

\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_nx^n\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=0}^m b_nx^n\right)
&= \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n x^{i+j} a_i b_j\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}x^k\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^k a_ib_{k-i}}_{c_k}.
\end{align}

So in the end, the list $[c_0,...,c_k]$ is given by

$$c_k=\sum_{i=0}^k a_ib_{k-i}.$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to find, however, not in this form. We must find a recursive definition that inserts the coefficients into the list

Comment: I actually don't understand what these _steps_ should be in your question. Do you want to prove the correctness of above formula by induction and don't know which induction variable to choose?

Comment: I added an example of what I mean. I want the same thing but for multiplication

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea you're missing, I think, is

$$\left( a + x f(x) \right) \cdot g(x) = a \cdot g(x) + x (f(x) \cdot g(x)) $$

Comment: I can't seem to relate this to the question can you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: @Zed: Your basic approach of splitting the list of coefficients into the concatenation of the first term followed by the rest of the list is exactly the same thing in more traditional notation as writing a polynomial $h(x)$ in the form $c + x k(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to think about would be something like that:

$$f([],[])=[],$$
\begin{align}
f(s:L_1,L_2)&=s\cdot L_2 + (0:f(L_1,L_2)), \\
f(L_1,s:L_2)&=s\cdot L_1 + (0:f(L_1,L_2)).
\end{align}

The multiplication and addition are meant componentwise. If you add lists of different length, then make them equally long by appending zeros. I think there is no way without accessing the "inner" list elements

One problem with this list representation of polynomials is the ambiguity of representing the zero polynomial. All of the following lists will represent the same polynomial:

$$[], [0],[0,0],...,[0,...,0],...$$

and the presented rescursive procedure will distingish them: $f(L,[])=0\cdot L$. More general

$$f(L,[\underbrace{0,...,0}_n])=(0\cdot L):[\underbrace{0,...,0}_n]=[\underbrace{0,...,0}_{n+\text{ length of }L}].$$

And you will have this problem in any multiplication:

\begin{align}
1\cdot 1 \overset{\sim}=f([1],[1])&=f(1:[],[1])\\
&=1\cdot[1]+(0:f([],[1]))\\
&=[1]+(0:[0])\\
&=[1]+[0,0] = [1,0]\overset{\sim}=1
\end{align}

So it would be recommended to trim trailing zeros after any calculation. Alternatively, instead of appending zeros to fix unqual length in list addition, at first, try to trim trailing zeros.

Comment: I don't think $x= [1]$ ?

Comment: You are right. I'm already busy fixing my answer.